# Can't read user input inside the Docker using Maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, docker, fabric8, docker-maven-plugin

#### Description

I'm writing a simple console application that starts in a Docker container, reads user input and processes it. For automating Docker I use [docker-maven-plugin](https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin).
The code for reading user input is the following:

`new Scanner(System.in).nextLine()`

Tried also the following:

`new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine()`

Running an application without Docker works in both cases.

I run the docker with command:
`mvn clean docker:build docker:run`

However in Docker when it comes to user input the code simply returns `null` and doesn't block for user input.  In case of `Scanner` I get `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found` which is basically the same.

I've found a similar issue on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25378143/1889928) where passing the command line parameters `-i -t`seem to help.

Is there any way I could add these command line parameters to `Maven` run configuration? Or any ideas why this issue happens?

#### Info

- Maven version : 3.3.9
- Docker version : 1.13.1

Comment: You realize docker containers run in a virtual machine which is separate from ur PC right? U need to ssh to the container then use ur java app from there. Which brings the question, why do u need to run ur app with docker?

Comment: @EanV Yes, sure I understand. The Java app is starting automatically by Maven plugin using `<cmd>` option after container startup, but the question is about execution of the Java app from docker container and why system input is not blocking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible with [docker-maven-plugin](https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin). See [this](https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin/issues/588).

I also agree with rhuss (last comment in the link) as well. You are using maven which is a build tool and then starting containers which will probably help you in some way to build-test something. Also, if you refer to [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground) section in docker documentation, it says

> Specifying -t is forbidden when the client standard output is redirected or piped

which probably a build plugin will do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The solution which worked for me is building an image with `mvn docker:build` and then connecting to it using `docker run -i -t [image-name]`